# getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when working with jsp and codemirror js lib

Tags: javascript, jsp, codemirror

i'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` when passing code as string to .setValue codemirror function that's my script

```
             <form action="submit.jsp" method="POST" id="ajax">
             <select name="language" onchange="selectLanguage()" 
                  id="select_language">
                   <option title="text/x-csrc" value="1">c</option>
                   <option title="text/x-java" value="2">java</option>
                   <option title="text/x-c++src" value="3">c++</option>

            </select>
                <textarea name="code" rows="20" cols="150" id="codemirror- 
                textarea"><%
                    if(solution.getCode() != null){
                        out.print(solution.getCode());
                    }
                    %></textarea>

 <script type="text/javascript">               
 var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codemirror- 
 textarea"), {
 lineNumbers: true,
 styleActiveLine: true,
 matchBrackets: true,
 extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
 mode:"text/x-csrc"
 });


var input = document.getElementById("select_language");
function selectLanguage() {
var mode = input.options[input.selectedIndex].title;
var lang = input.options[input.selectedIndex].value;
var value = "<%= problem.getCCode() %>";

editor.setOption("mode", mode);

editor.setValue(value);
}

</script>
```

here's the image in the console and the code snippet wishing to display on language select change
[codesnippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edBPC.png)

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution 
the new lines in the code string was causing error in initializing by using "template literals" in JavaScript which are these quotes `` i manged to escape new lines like this

```
            var value = `<%=solution.getCode() %>`;
```